# Code Behaving Differently On Different IDE

Tags: java, input, ide

I am writing a program that takes information about a track and field competition and then does some computation with it. The issue I'm having now is only in the first user input section.

I first wrote my code in BlueJ and it worked fine. Then, I tried compiling it in JCreator and started getting this error where the program would only receive 3 user inputs before going onto the next piece of code when it should have received 5 (which it did when I compiled in BlueJ).

When I placed a `System.out.println` statement after the input statement however, the program (in JCreator) DID receive all 5 statements before proceeding. When I commented it out again, it only received 3 statements before continuing. Here is the code below.

```
    String[] events = new String[5];

    System.out.println("Please enter the 5 events in this competition.");
    for(int i = 0; i < events.length; i++)
    {
        events[i] = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

This is the output with the `System.out.println` statement.

[image]

This is the output with the `System.out.println` statement **commented out.**

[image]

Comment: What happens when you change `events` to a `String[6]`? or 7? 8? 9? I'm guessing a pattern will emerge where you'll get something close to n/2 inputs.

Comment: Please try adding the following after the code you posted in the question, and tell us what you see: `for(int i = 0; i < events.length; i++) System.out.println(i + events[i]);`

Comment: This is the output: 
100m dash
200m dash
300m dash
0100m dash
1
2200m dash
3
4300m dash

Comment: The '1' before 2200 and '3' before 4300 are on their own separate lines

Comment: When I changed the length of events to 6, the code would take 4 values before continuing. It was still 4 at length of 7 but became 5 at length of 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
events[i] = input.nextLine();
```

to

```
String newLine;
while( (newLine = input.nextLine()).isEmpty() );
events[i] = newLine;
```

That should consume the extra **newline** characters and leave you with just the legitimate input in `events`.

Comment: So far so good, I need to do a little more debugging to make sure this code functions properly with the rest of my code. Will accept as answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The possible cause of your problem is **newline** characters, which are interpreted as line. It seems you are having additional newline characters in your input buffer.

You may check your IDE what character is provided when an enter key is pressed.

It seems you are using **Scanner** class to read input. You may try to wrap your System.in with InputStreamReader, that might help. (not sure, try it out)

`Scanner input = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 events[i]=input.nextLine();`

Instead you may also try to use **BufferedReader** to read the input.

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 events[i]=reader.readLine();`

Hope it will help!!

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those worked. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: I believe the diagnosis is correct: it's **newline** characters. What to do?